# Collapse dual lines to centerline doesn't exist in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, generalization, arcgis-pro, data-management, advanced-license-level

I have ArcGIS Pro build 3308 (Ver. 1.1) and wish to collapse two parallel lines into one, however it appears that this function no longer exists - I have also tried using python for this and received an error stating

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CollapseDualLinesToCentreLine_arc'`.

Was the function that allowed this to be done taken out in the pro version of ArcGIS?[image: Generalisation Toolbox]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [List of Tools not available in ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/appendices/unavailable-tools.htm) "collapse dual lines to center line" was not brought over to ArcGIS Pro. I am not sure how to combine the lines. You could try to merge and dissolve the lines with a common field. Or you could delete one of the lines and take an off-center line as the represented line. ArcGIS Pro is a step forward in terms of 3D abilities, but a step back in terms of 2D capabilities. You may want to try to use ArcGIS 10.3 (ArcMap) to perform the function, and then bring that single line into ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 2):

Correct.  That functionality is not part of ArcGIS Pro.  Among others.

[Link to tools that are not available in Pro.](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/appendices/unavailable-tools.htm)

Answer (score 0):

ArcGIS Pro version 2.5 has the 'Merge Divided Roads' geoprocessing tool which can be used instead of the 'Collapse Dual Lines to Centre Line'tool